# How to avoid conflicting terminal command with getstream-cli?

Tags: javascript, bash, oh-my-zsh

I installed https://github.com/GetStream/stream-cli but I also installed imagemagick with homebrew on MacOS 10.14.6 (Mojave). But the `stream` command from stream-cli conflicts with the `stream` command from imagemagick, so when I try and run it the system thinks I want to run imagemagick.

What's a good way to avoid this? (I'm also using oh-my-zsh...)

Answer (score 0):

You can set `aliases` in `oh-my-zsh`, via `~/.zshrc`. You could do:

```
alias gsStream="path/to/getStream/bin/stream"
alias imStream="path/to/imagick/bin/stream"
```

Note: I'm not sure where the `stream` command is stored for each of these, but you should be able to find an use the correct path.

Then run `source .zshrc` from `~` directory, and any new terminal windows will have access to these commands. Simply run `gsStream` and `imStream` instead of `stream` and you're good to go.